# Date of last index rebuild for Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, index, index-tuning

is there any way we could check the last time when a database in MySql was rebuilt?

Comment: MySQL does not record such.  What do you want it for?

Comment: i am doing index rebuild by a scheduled Job, so i need to confirm if that job successfully rebuilt the indexes of a mySQL DB

Comment: There is info in `information_schema` that lists what indexes exist for each table.  Also `SHOW CREATE TABLE` lists the indexes.  Do you have evidence that they are not being rebuilt?

Comment: i have manually rebuilt so i am sure the rebuilt is complete but wanted to get some data from the DB, i even cehcked the when modified date of DB using  SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE NAME = 'tablename''; but unfortunately the update date is blank